# How to compile libwebp for arm64 on Mac with Apple's chip M1?

Tags: macos, compilation, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I have a Mac with Big Sur and Apple's chip M1, which is ARM's chip, as you probably know.

Problem arises when I try to include Google's libwebp.a to my project. Xcode says that "it is not build for architecture arm64".

I installed Homebrew and then installed libwebp with `brew install libwebp` (or similar, I am writing from memory), opened directory where it was saved, copied libwebp.a and Xcode gave me same error.

Then I downloaded source and did:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

I copied compiled library and Xcode again gave me the same error. It seems that libwebp is not compiled for arm64.

Is it even possible to compile it for arm64 on Big Sur, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

To use brew on Apples M1 you need to use two installs:

- First (the one for ARM): `/opt/homebrew`
- Second (the one for x86): `/usr/local`

There are pretty good articles how to build a side-by-side install:

- https://soffes.blog/homebrew-on-apple-silicon
- https://noahpeeters.de/posts/apple-silicon/homebrew-setup/

When you got this working you need to remove the old lib (that was built with the x86 arch) and install it freshly using the arm packages.